# Media is not fetching with Instagram API

Tags: php, api, instagram

I am trying to fetch media in a particular place with Instagram API, I am following this link: https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/media/#get_media_search to get media in a particular location and trying this: https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/search?lat=48.858844&lng=2.294351&access_token=XXXXX

But this is given me empty data {"meta": {"code": 200}, "data": []}

Can someone tell me why I am getting empty data, even in example they showing the data in response.

Comment: Your access token includes the required scope?

Comment: Hi  CBroe

Yes scope is included, I set this in scope : 'basic',  'likes',  public_content',  'follower_list',  'comments',  'relationships'.

Answer (score 0):

This will show only public to read any public profile info and media on a user’s behalf not private

Comment: Hi Gurpreet, thanks for answering.
My profile is public but this is not working

Comment: I tried other APIs

https://api.instagram.com/v1/locations/search?lat=48.858844&lng=2.294351&access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
https://api.instagram.com/v1/locations/{location-id}?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN

they are working but this is not getting the data

Answer (score 0):

I am able to get my own media on which I have added location, but I want to fetch media by passing the latitude and longitude of any location. It seems as I logged in, it is like combined with my access token.